# Can you use the telekinetic feat vertically?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

So the Telekinetic feat allows you to attempt to move another creature 5 feet with a bonus action

> As a bonus action, you can try to telekinetically shove one creature you can see within 30 feet of you. When you do so, the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw (DC 8 + your proficiency bonus + the ability modifier of the score increased by this feat) or be moved 5 feet toward you or away from you. A creature can willingly fail this save.

1. Could you use this on a creature that is flying directly above you to push them down toward you?
2. Could you use this out of combat to help an ally climb a rope up toward you?

Comment: Related: [Can Pushing Attack push someone upwards?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80930) | [Can you push someone upwards into the air?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95115) | [Can Thorn Whip lift the target 10 feet into the air?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158337) | [Grasp of Hadar: can using it while flying cause falling damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168828) | [What happens when you use the Telekinetic shove from Tasha's when flying directly above your target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178875) | [Can thunderwave push upwards?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149724)

Comment: Extremely related: "[Does the bonus-action shove from the (UA) Telekinetic feat move the target through the air, or only on the ground?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176768)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Telekinetic does not stipulate an absolute direction.

The direction of the push and pull of the Telekinetic feat is not defined in an absolute sense - it does not require the movement to be horizontal, vertical, or otherwise. Rather it is defined in a relative sense - relative to you. So if a creature is directly overhead, “toward or away from you” is, naturally, in the vertical direction.

Comment: So, if you throw yourself prone right next to the opponent and use the feat, would that shove the creature upwards? :)

Comment: @Senmurv Unfortunately no.

Comment: Is that because of the grid (squares) or what is your reasoning. I guess it's the "directly overheard" bit. However, where did you get this from in the spell's description? ...what if you don't use a grid?  In a "relative sense" would the prone example not work?